# Inserting an array within an object construction, constructed based on a query

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I construct an object using a query if I also need to insert values in the parent object?

Clearly I'm using the wrong syntax.

EDITED, getting closer:

```
insert into myTable
select
    mybigtype('foo', 'bar', 'fizzle', myarrayoflittletypes(
        select ref(S)
        from anotherTable S
        where S.stname='dingle'
            or S.stname='fangle')));
```

mylittletype was created as:

```
CREATE TYPE myarrayoflittletypes AS VARRAY(20) OF REF mylittletype
```

anotherTable was created as:

```
CREATE TABLE anotherTable OF mylittletype
```

mybigtype has a few strings and a type that's defined to hold an array of references to mylittletype objects.  So I want to be able to insert a row into this table that creates an object of type mybigtype with the array constructed based on a query that I define.  Can I do this all in one insertion?  Or do I need to put in a null placeholder and UPDATE this field subsequently?

Oracle's current complaint is

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

So how can I get the multiple OID returns to this query into the array in the object I'm constructing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this so that I can insert multiple rows into my array from a single query, but the following worked:

```
insert into myTable
    values(mybigtype('foo', 'bar', 'fizzle', myarrayoflittletypes(
        (select ref(S)
        from anotherTable S
        where S.stname='dingle'),
        (select ref(S)
         from anotherTable S
         where S.stname='fangle'))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it!

```
insert into myTable
select 
    mybigtype('foo', 'bar', 'fizzle', myarrayoflittletypes(
        (select
            ref(S.mylittletype)
        from anotherTable S
        where S.mylittletype.stname='dingle
            or S.mylittletype.stname='fangle')));
```

Comment: Thanks much, this gets me most of the way there - this query returns multiple rows, and I want to add them each to the array.  Is that possible?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, as the array should add all rows returned in the subquery to myarrayoflittletypes.  What's giving you more than it should?

Comment: (select ref(S)
    *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Should I be using a different keyword to indicate that all rows should be added?

Comment: Also, the outer select statement needs to select from something - does it matter from what I select?

Comment: How're you handling the array creation, since it's balking at multiple rows being returned?  Is myarrayoflittletypes() a user-defined function which parses the results and puts them into a concatenated list?

And the outer select just wraps the values up into a select statement so you can have multiple rows if need be.

Comment: I created the array as: CREATE TYPE myarrayoflittletypes AS VARRAY(20) OF REF mylittletype;, and S was created as: CREATE TABLE anotherTable OF mylittletype; - thank you again for the help, Oracle's documentation leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: Well, most of my experience is MSSQL and MySQL, so I apologize if I'm a little slow.  What does select myarrayoflittletypes(...) get you?

Comment: The inner query yields two rows with single entries of long keys (presumably OID's).